# Failure message from Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I am getting the message

> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

while trying to solve the following equation:

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers, Reduce[p + 2 s == (2 r (p + 2 b) + 2 b + p) (2 r + 1)^n, r, Reals]]
```

How can I get my code to work?

Comment: Not an answer, but it good to be aware that `Assuming` only works with functions that take an `Assumptions` option, which `Reduce` doesn't.  You can append `&& Element[n, Integers]` to the equation instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a solution from `Solve`. Your equation can be rewritten

```
(1 + 2 r)^(1 + n) == (p + 2 s)/(2 b + p)
```

Making what I hope you can accept as a reasonable assumption about `2 b + p`, I evaluated

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && 2 b + p != 0, 
  Solve[(1 + 2 r)^(1 + n) == (p + 2 s)/(2 b + p), r]]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> ```
> {{r -> 1/2 (-1 + (p/(2 b + p) + (2 s)/(2 b + p))^(1/(1 + n)))}}
> ```

In this case, `Reduce` won't do any good, but perhaps you can live without knowing if the solution found by `Solve` may not be complete. I think you need only note that the formal solution fails for `n = -1`.

Comment: nice I missed that simple factoring ...